# What is the difference between call "dumpmem" and "dumpreg" commands (masm615)?

Tags: assembly

What is the difference between call "dumpmem" and "dumpregs" commands (masm615)?

```
call dumpmem
call dumpregs
```

Answer (score 1):

These are not masm functions, they are from some library. Probably the irvine one. Obviously dumpmem dumps memory, while dumpregs dumps the registers:

```
DumpMem PROC
;
; Writes a range of memory to standard output
; in hexadecimal.
; Receives: ESI = starting offset, ECX = number of units,
;           EBX = unit size (1=byte, 2=word, or 4=doubleword)
; Returns:  nothing
```

```
DumpRegs PROC
;
; Displays EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, EBP, ESP in
; hexadecimal. Also displays the Zero, Sign, Carry, and
; Overflow flags.
; Receives: nothing.
; Returns: nothing.
```